# Load images from S3 bucket to uiTableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, amazon-s3

I have a table view that loads images from s3 bucket and set some data with the images in my cell.

I call my cell at

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellDish:DishTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DishCell", for: indexPath) as! DishTableViewCell

    cellDish.setDish(dish: brain.listOfDishes[indexPath.row])


    return cellDish }
```

in my tableviewcell I have a func called setDish :

```
func setDish (dish: Dish)
{
    var StringPrice = dish.DishPrice
    StringPrice.append("$")
    self.la_name.text = dish.DishName
    self.la_price.text = StringPrice
    self.la_des.text = dish.DishDes
    self.downloadData(dish: dish, completion: { success in
        guard success else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {     
            self.dish_image.image = UIImage(data: dish.DishData!)!

        }
    })


}


func downloadData(dish:Dish,completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()
    let s3Bucket = "<my bucket name>"

    transferUtility.downloadData(fromBucket: s3Bucket, key: dish.DishImage, expression: expression) {(task, url, data, error) in
        if error != nil {print(error)
            completion(false)
        }
        else {

            dish.DishData = data!

        }
        completion(true)
    }

}
```

I want it to show me the dish data without the image until the image is downloaded and then show it to me as well (I want it to be not on the main thread of course ). 
I'm not sure why but right now all the cells download their images and only then everything loads up together.

Comment: Check out this library. It should help you with the async downloading of the images. You can set a placeholder while they are downloading. https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: Do you know what thread `downloadData` is operating on?

Comment: I'm not sure , all I know it's not on main

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 Updated Code :**
Load url asynchronous will update automatically

```
extension UIImageView 
{
public func imageFromServerURL(urlString: String) 
{

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.image = image
            })

        }).resume()
    }}
```

**Swift 2.2 Code :**

```
 extension UIImageView {
        public func imageFromServerURL(urlString: String) {

            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    self.image = image
                })

            }).resume()
        }}
```